# How to compare 2 objects of generic type

Tags: linked-list, compareto

Is there a way to compare two objects that are generic? I'm supposed to find the largest object in a linked list. My first guess was to use the Object's class compareTo method, but I couldn't get that to work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the language is Java. (since you mentioned Object and compareTo)

I suggest you to have a have a look into [Comparator](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and [Comparable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interfaces.